# Loop Increment for every click in python/ pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

I have created simple image viewer using python/pyqt. I would like to change the image in the lable for every "next" or "previous" button(s) are clicked. I used the following code for increament:-

```
if self.sender().objectName() == "next_button":
            for i, name in list(enumerate(array)):
                myPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join("data", "images", name))
                myScaledPixmap = myPixmap.scaled(self.ui.label.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                #self.ui.label.setScaledContents(True) # For streching the image up to entire lable...
                self.ui.label.setPixmap(myScaledPixmap)
                print i, name
                break
```

As expected, the image is struck at first in the list. Any lead to solve the issue is appriciated.

Comment: It is just name. Typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first convert it to an iterator, then call `next(my_iterator)` each time you want the next thing

```
from itertools import cycle
class Whatever:
    fnames = cycle(["im1.gif","im2.gif","im3.gif"])
    def on_button(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if self.sender().objectName() == "next_button":
           next_path = os.path.join("data", "images", next(self.fname))
           myPixMap = QtGui.QPixmap(next_path)
           ...
```

this will then cycle through those filenames with a new one each click

for example

```
from Tkinter import *
from itertools import cycle
#from tkinter import ttk
def on_button():
    label.set(next(names))

root = Tk()
root.title("Iterator")

mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.grid()
names = cycle(["im1.gif","im2.gif","im3.gif"])
label = StringVar()
label.set("Click Next To Cycle Through")
Label(mainframe, textvariable=label).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
Button(mainframe, text="next", command=on_button).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: sorry. This does not move to next file path. Can you give sone exapme to use this class?

Comment: It works if you are already inside the loop. But in my case the entire function is recalled whenever button is clicked and the list is re assigned again. Therefore, I could see only the first element from the list on every click.

Comment: the list should not be reassigned ... you need to make it an iterator in your `__init__` function or something...

Comment: Why does your example show Tkinter code? The question is about PyQt.

Comment: because the question really is agnostic to the gui language and Im not familliar with qt to write up an example as quickly as I could with tkinter